# Element from model is not defined

Tags: python, django

Im working with django, building a web app. I have most stuff working. The general structure is I have a user tied to a list of elements. When I click on those elements, I get a 404 page not found error.

Heres some of `models.py`:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    #user that created the event

    #event title
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    #time created
    created = models.DateField('Date Created',auto_now_add=True)

    #description of event from user
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    #address of event if existant
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class User(models.Model):

    attending = models.ManyToManyField('Event', related_name='User_attending')
    hosting = models.ForeignKey('Event', related_name='User_hosting')

    gender = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    fName = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    lName = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

From `views.py`, when I try and access the html page attached to my "event" object, I get a 404 error because my code doesnt recognize "Event".

```
from list.models import *

def event(request, id):
     #e = Event()
     #code.interact(local = locals())
     try:
         e = Event.objects.get(User_hosting=id)
     except Event.DoesNotExist:
         raise Http404
     if e.user_id != request.user.id:
         raise Http404
     #code.interact(local = locals())
     return render_to_response('event/event.html', {'event':e})
```

When I use the shell, `e = Event.objects.get(User_hosting=id)` it says that "Event is not defined".

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting when trying to access the template?

Comment: You would get a 404 either if the event object isn't found or if there as a user ID mismatch (a 401 or 403 response is probably more suitable in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import any modules or classes you want to use in the shell. Try this (where `appname` is the name of your app.

```
from appname.models import Event
```

Comment: I forgot to include that I did have "from list.models import *" in my views.py. I tried explicitly including Event, but no such luck.

Comment: Sure. But when you're using the shell, you still need to import there.